# 2008 Toyota Corolla 141 Fuel Consumption Too High

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption, corolla

I recently got a Toyota Corolla 141. The petrol consumption is too bad. It does only around **7.5-8 Km/l**. Could you please let me know the reason behind this ?

I was told that the vehicle is too heavy and the engine is not power enough to pickup? Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add year make model completely in your question.

Comment: @Dee Yes Sure. Its Toyota Corolla 141. YOM: 2008 Make: Toyota Model: Corolla

Comment: Have you looked at the spark plugs? Did you notice the color of its tips? Any other symptoms like back fires? Any excessive oil build up in particular areas? Smoke from exhaust color and smell?

Comment: What's the engine? This translates to ~12.5/100km, which is not necessarily bad, depending on the engine.

Comment: @Dee No concerns like that ... Still it is 35K driven and was imported brand new via Toyota Agents. Could it be coz of the weight of the car ?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I earlier had Toyota Corolla 121 which was very good on fuel. It did around 13-15 Km/l. It was VVTi engine but the model I talk is Dual VVTi. So fuel consumption is not compared to that.

Comment: Is it a 1.6 VVTi? Corolla isn't a heavy car, I would have a hard time believing that 12.5l/100km is a normal figure for a 1.6 unless you constantly floor it and drive in the city under heavy traffic conditions every day.

Comment: So what is your idea @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing ?

Comment: Look for faults causing high fuel consumption if you get these figures under light driving conditions. Air filter, coolant temperature sensor, oxygen sensors, fuel pressure regulator, etc.

Comment: Vaccum leak... Fuel ratio.... Intake leak..  You would be stepping on the pedal to compensate and waste fuel essentially....

Comment: As others have illuded to, there are many reasons that can cause increased fuel consumption. Everything from the temperature outside being colder to something leaking to even something like bad driving mannerisms.

Answer (score 3):

The EPA (US - Environmental Protection Agency) lists the mileage for this car at 27 **MPG** City, and 37 **MPG** highway. That's roughly 11.47 **Km/l** city and 15.73 **Km/l** highway. Granted, these ratings are under absolutely perfect conditions so they are a fantasy when it comes to real world combined mileage. So let's call it a combined of roughly 26 **MPG** which is 11.05 **Km/l**. Still a good ~40% better than what you're seeing.

At least you can eliminate the weight of the vehicle and the power of the engine. A more powerful engine would use more fuel not less, so you need not worry about those things you can't change. This looks to be something wrong with the car. And running rich is a very good possibility, and that means the comment suggesting looking at the spark plugs is a very good idea. If they are dark and sooty looking you're probably running rich. Since you just got the car a tune-up would be a good idea. I just recently bought a 2000 Toyota Camry and the first thing was an oil change, spark plug replacement, air filter, fuel filter, and whatever repair items it needed. If yours needs no repairs you would still be served well by doing the maintenance items I listed. Should be fairly inexpensive especially if you do them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My finding is that the first 3 gear ratios are too short and that it requires to run at around 3,500 to 4,000 RPM, and the speed to be around 60-70 KMPH to change to 4th gear and even higher to change to 5th... so in normal city driving in peak traffic time, fuel consumption is around 8KM/L on 95 Octane Petrol, and highway comes to around 13 is you're heavy on the gas, and around 19 on 'pulse-glide' method.